# × TypeError: Cannot read property 'original' of undefined React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to access the properties of the data I returned from the API, I can access some of the properties but when I try returning the image property of the data, I keep getting cannot read property of undefined, the image property is an object in the data.  Here is the code below.

```
class GifDetail extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      gifImages: [],
    };
  }

  async componentDidMount() {
    const url = `https://api.giphy.com/v1/gifs/${this.props.match.params.id}?api_key=GuN18iG06KnZHBSYQR***Cw2YCZHN37`;
    const response = await fetch(url);
    const data = await response.json();
    console.log(data);
    this.setState({ gifImages: data.data });
  }

  render() {
    const { gifImages } = this.state;

    return (
      <div>
         <img
          src={`${this.state.gifImages.images.fixed_height_small_still.url}`}
          width="100"
          className="img-fluid"
        /> //this line is returning undefined 

        <p>{gifImages.images.original}</p> // this is the line that is returning undefined 
        <p>{gifImages.username}</p>
        <p>{gifImages.url}</p>
        <p>{gifImages.title}</p>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default GifDetail;
```

Answer (score 0):

Apply check  `gifImages.images && gifImages.images.original` this way:

Instead of:

```html
<p>{gifImages.images.original}</p>
```

write:

```html
{ gifImages.images && <p>{gifImages.images.original}</p> }
```

Comment: do you mean i should put in an If statement?

Comment: In state, you are initializing gitImages as array and in <img/> u are accesing it directly.